# Cannot add custom domain to firebase

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, firebase-console

The custom domain wizard in firebase cannot go in the "verify ownership" stage. When I look at the web dev console I see a lot of 503 errors.

Is the spark plan not enough to have a custom domain ? Is the system broken ? Have I skip a step ?

Comment: If you're seeing errors or having problems configuring something in the Firebase console, you should contact Firebase support directly.  Stack Overflow will be of no help to you.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Could you see document? https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#verify-domain-ownership And It may take up to 24 hours after you point your A records to Firebase Hosting.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who ends up here, I did forward this on to Firebase Support.

They responded with 'That error appears when developers have a GSuite account. To solve the issue, reach out to your GSuite organization admin/owner to get the Search Console enabled. The following [Google support article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6237949) will provide the steps to enable the Search Console.'

Indeed, after enabling the Google Search Console, it did proceed to the Verify Domain step.